# Add C#-calculated columns to tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization, ef-fluent-api

I'm building an Entity Framework data context for a pre-existing application. As this application has a nice clean set of POCOs that define the domain model, I opted to use EF's Code First to generate the database from these classes so that we don't have to maintain two separate models; in theory the database will be migrated to match whatever we do to the POCOs, with just the occasional bit of mapping required in the `OnModelCreating()` override.

My problem is that one of the domain classes has a property of type `Dictionary<string, object>` that's being used to store state data (which is being read from a key-value store elsewhere, so we're stuck with that format). My first thought was that we could just apply `[NotMapped]` to this property, and then create a `string` property in which the getter and setter just serialised/deserialised the `Dictionary` to XML, JSON or whatever.

The issue is that we're not changing the domain classes with database-specific stuff, so I have to do all that from the data access assembly. I know how to apply the `NotMapped` attribute in the Fluent Configuration API, but I can't work out how to set up a column for the serialised parameters. On the model, it would look like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public IDictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; }
public string JSONParameters
{
    get
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Parameters);
    }
    set
    {
        Parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(value);
    }
}
```

How would I write the equivalent code in the Fluent Configuration API? Is it even possible?

Comment: You want the JSONParameters property to exist only virtually in the model not on our domain class?

Comment: I'd like the database to have a JSON column, and the domain class to have a Dictionary.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. you will need the string Property in your domain object. But you could make it private, protected or internal if you want.